# SQL. Is it possible to make "stat" in query?

Tags: sql

I have table `matches`. Column name like: `match_id,team_1_id, team_2_id, team_1_win, team_2_win, day, etc`.

I need to make "STAT" like `winrate_team_1`, `winrate_team_2`. It look like  I need to count all wins and losses of team (**IMPORTANT** all before current day or match). Then make stat `all_wins/(all_wins + all_losses)`

I have no any ideas how to do this in SQL.

So is it possible to make this hard request by SQL? or may be it is better do on "my side", like by Python?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
  match_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  radiant_win boolean,
  radiant_team_id integer,
  dire_team_id integer,
);
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it.

Comment: Put the exact schema of your table `matches`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)